# In linux how to archive and compress multiple files into one and remove source files?

Tags: linux, compression, archive, bzip2, xz

I have below files in a directory.

```
file001
file002
.
.
file009
```

I need to compress them into one and remove original/source files (`file001 .. file009`) so I can free up some disk space.

This is what I did:
Archived all files into one using below command

```
tar -cvf file00.tar file00*
```

Then compressed the archived file using below command

```
xz file00.tar
```

previously I had archived and compressed using single command

```
tar -cJvf file00.tar.xz file00*
```

`xz` has done a fine job, compressed 10GB file into less than 400MB but I have several problems with these methods:

1. Old/source files are not removed
2. xz takes huge time

My question is, **is there any way I can archive and compress multiple files into one using single command that'll also remove source files?** Is there any other compression tool that's efficient as xz but works faster?

I've seen in some other sites that I can use multiple cores/threads to boost xz process but haven't tried myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try [`pixz`](https://github.com/vasi/pixz) which is parallel variant of `xz` tool (there is also `pxz` parallel variant of xz): `tar -Ipixz -cf foo.tpxz foo/` (there is `-I compressor` option of tar to select non-standard compressor).

Comment: You could try zstdmt. For 4 cores at high compression, it gives something like that : `tar -cvf - file00* | zstdmt -19 -T4 > file00.tar.zst`

Answer (score 3):

You may try [`pixz`](https://github.com/vasi/pixz) which is parallel variant of `xz` tool (or `pxz` parallel variant of xz)):

```
tar -Ipixz -cf foo.tpxz foo/`
```

There is `-I compressor` option of tar to select non-standard compressor, and it should be before `f` option as f option requires the string argument.

And for deletion there is option in GNU Tar https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/remove-files.html (why it is in the "4.4 Options Used by `--extract`" section??)

> Removing Files
>
> *See The section is too terse. Something more to add? An example, maybe?*
>
> `--remove-files`
>
> Remove files after adding them to the archive.

I didn't test it, but it was listed in https://serverfault.com/questions/283355/correct-way-of-using-the-remove-files-option-with-tar (and https://superuser.com/questions/96860)  again used before `-f` option:

```
tar --remove-files -cvfj archive.tar.bz2 archive/
```

So, combining both options (after installation of `pixz`; this is still can be opened by classic `xz` tool, and can be renamed as `archive.tar.xz` too):

```
tar  -Ipixz --remove-files -cJvf file00.tpxz file00*
```

or with `xz`:

```
tar  -Ixz --remove-files -cJvf file00.tar.xz file00*
```

PS: There are other parallel compressors: `pigz` (gzip format), pbzip2 and lbzip2 (bzip2 format, not so compact and slower than xz and gzip). There are also fast compressors like `lz4`/`lz5` or facebook's `zstd`. And there is [`lrzip`](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/lrzip/) which can use several threads for compression and can find repetitions of data over long distance, and then compress using lzma ([by default](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/lrzip/README.md), xz-like method) or classic gz or faster LZO or very slow and effective ZPAQ.